# Add another field to paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I have already added the paperclip gem using `rails generate paperclip pin image`
However I would like to add a field called :`title which would be a string`.

I attempted to add it to my **pin.rb** file

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :image, :title
```

And then put it in my view **html.erb** page but encountered an error :`title did not schema`.  How would I add a field to the pins table in rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create another migration for that (or just add it in the migration created by paperclip but it's better to add another migration).  You can do that by running the following

```
rails g migration add_title_to_pins title
rake db:migrate
```